# Estimating the price-effect of an electricity interconnector in exporting- and importing scenarios?

Tags: regression, causality

In my research I am trying to estimate how the introduction of an electricity interconnector between two different markets (A and B) has affected the electricity price in market A. I would preferably differentiate the price effect between the export- and import hours, that should yield negative and positive coefficients respectively.

I have looked into interaction terms and nested interaction terms to capture this effect in a regression model, but I feel like this might be a dead end. Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated.

I apologize if this is a very basic question, or if it is not well-defined/too broad. Please let me know if I can clarify this further.

Comment: It might help for you to share the model set-up and estimation you already have :)
Without knowing more, [difference-in-differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences) is a technique that comes to mind.